# Android device administration not enforcing for apps in Android for work

Tags: android

I would like to disable the Camera on Android devices(Ignoring rooted devices). So far successfully using Android [device administration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) to disable Camera. However, camera in containers such as Android for Work is able to bypass the policy (Samsung Secure Folder as well, but that can be disabled using KNOX). Are there other ways to enforce disable camera other then device administration?

For Samsung devices, cameras can be disabled entirely using KNOX. But other android devices such as Sony and LG does not have such capability. Does this mean there are no way to enforce camera disable?